# Jersey 2 Dependency injection + weblogic 12c issue

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c

We are using the Jersey 2.21 and Weblogic 12c.
In our application we are using the Dependency Injection.

- while injecting the normal objects i handle through Hk2 framework and register in `AbstractBinder`.
- Now the issue is while injecting the parameterized class or `javax.enterprise.event.Event` with parameter, Dependencies are not resolving. Having the below error.

Can any one please help on this issue?

Example:

```
@Inject
private Event<MachineAddedEvent>  myobject;
```

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=Event<MachineAddedEvent> machineAddedEvent;,parent=JerseyService,qualifiers={@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1132256571)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:777)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:740)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:710)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
```

Comment: Ex: @Inject
 private transient Event<MachineAddedEvent> machineAddedEvent; With this kind of code dependencies are not working

Comment: Basically CDI Event using HK2 + Jersey2 combination is not working. Dependency Injection is not working. Can any one please help. I am struggling since many days.               Ex: Ex:
 @Inject
 private javax.enterprise.event.Event<packageEvent> packageRecievedEvent;